# Create another controller and model not working on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just want to ask if how can I add another controller and model on codeigniter. So far I have 1 controller and 1 model for now and they are working now I tried adding 1 more controller and 1 more model like this

`controller`

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Investor extends CI_Controller {

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * Maps to the following URL
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
     *  - or -
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
     *  - or -
     * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
     * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
     *
     * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
     * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
     * @see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
     */
     public function __construct()
    {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('investor_m');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library("pagination");
        $this->load->library("session");
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Lending System Login';
        $data["count_investor"] = $this->investor_m->get_all_investor();
        $this->template->load('default_layout','contents','investors', $data);
    }
}
```

`model`

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class investor_m extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_all_investor()
    {
        return $this->db->count_all("investor");
    }
}
```

and on my `view`

```
<?php foreach ($count_investor as $rec){echo $rec;} ?>
```

Could someone help me out why it's not working . The error says that

> A PHP Error was encountered
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: count_investor
>
> Filename: views/investors.php
>
> Line Number: 12

could someone help me out.

Comment: can you try to var_dump($this->investor->get_all_investor()); die; on the first line of index() function
and see what the array has ?

Comment: it doesn't display any sir

Comment: If `var_dump($this->investor->get_all_investor());` shows nothing then that is your problem. That means that in the model the call `$this->db->count_all("investor");` Is failing for some reason. Is "investor" the name of the table? If it is, does it have any records? Do you understand that `db->count_all` returns an integer which represents the number of rows in the table? Do you have error reporting turned on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention wrong class name in both model and controller, you create model name with **employee_m** and you try to extend it with name **investor**. It should be like below

**Model**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class investor extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_all_investor()
    {
        return $this->db->count_all("investor");
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Investor extends CI_Controller {

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * Maps to the following URL
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
     *  - or -
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
     *  - or -
     * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
     * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
     *
     * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
     * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
     * @see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
     */
     public function __construct()
    {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('investor');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library("pagination");
        $this->load->library("session");
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Lending System Login';
        $data["count_investor"] = $this->investor->get_all_investor();
        $this->template->load('default_layout','contents','investors', $data);
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: still didn't work sir . Do I need to setup any on the router?

Comment: You do not need to setup anything on the router.

Comment: $this->load->view('default_layout','contents','investors', $data), think this will work